# How to translate facebook like button on my forum?

Tags: translation

I have facecook like button plugin on my vanilla forum.
Although I added

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js#xfbml=1">
```

into my button code, it does not show the button in Turkish.

here is an example topic that you can see facebook button on my forum : http://www.herkesuzman.com/discussion/17/projeksiyona-baglaninca-ekran-coezuenuerlueguenuen-bozulmasis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem in the end by adding following code into my default.master.php file ;

```
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=iso-8859-9>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=windows-1254>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=x-mac-turkish>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the script to account for Turkish from this:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_us/all.js#xfbml=1">
```

the en_us part basically says English and then the form, which in this case is US English

For Turkish, however, you don't have to put the region/form, just the language.

Try this and let me know what you get:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/tr/all.js#xfbml=1">
```

Comment: thanks for the proposition @Melanie ,
I did what you told but I get still same result...

the button is still in English :( 

here is the result : [Result](http://www.herkesuzman.com/hutest/discussion/10/test-pockets-plugin-contentafter-comments)

Answer (score 0):

The facebook plugin is automatically located based on the user location. I'm from Spain, and I see the button in Spanish. I guess the same applies for the Turkish user base.

Comment: nope, I connect from Turkey but it's still in English.

Comment: Try this solution from someone with your same problem: http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/15498/solvedhow-to-translate-like-button/p1

Comment: that's me too :s no solutions yet...first day it was OK but then it was back to English again :(